# Which DBMSs offer index-organized tables?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, db2, informix

My current knowledge:

- Oracle does offer index-organized tables and defaults to heap-organized.
- I heard that SQL-Server uses only index-organized tables

I am especially interested in answers for MySQL, PostgreSQL, Informix and DB2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySql has clustered indexes but there appears to be limited control on these indexes.

[MySql clustered indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-index-types.html) and see this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585619/create-a-mysql-primary-key-without-a-clustered-index)

DB2 has MDC (multi-dimension cluster) which can effectively index organise the table in several ways.  I've never used them but you can probably just have a single dimension MDC which would be the same as a standard clustered index.

Oracle is a bit of a pain.  Last time I checked with its IOT implementation requires you create the table as IOT and you can't change it later, which is annoying when you want to load a load of data with no indexes for speed and then index it after.

Comment: Thanks! I'm willing to accept some pain for a sizeable chunk of performance ;-).

Comment: Now I looked up clustered index for Informix, et voilà it's there too! So, my candidate DBMSs all seem to support IOT aka clustering indexes.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server can store table data in either `Heap Structures` or `Clustered Index Structures`. If a table doesn't have a clustered index then it is considered a heap. For more details see here [Heap Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188270.aspx) and [Clustered Index Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As for Informix Dynamic Server (IDS) or Standard Engine (SE), they both support clustered and non-clustered indexes. IDS uses RSAM and SE uses C-ISAM B-Tree indexing. For both, when a cluster index is created, a table's rows are physically ordered in the same order as the index, but as new rows are added to the table, the row is physically placed at EOF (heap).

Comment: "... but as new rows are added to the table, the row is physically placed at EOF (heap). " Oh, that comes as a surprise. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: it would be nice for newly inserted rows to be physically placed in the datafile according to the cluster index, but think of all the work the engine would have to do to maintain this. performance would be a disaster!

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL offers clustered indexes.

The command `cluster <table> <index>` will order the database table physically according to the index. Subsequent data modifications will ignore this ordering. The ordering can be refreshed by issuing `cluster <table>`.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-cluster.html